# Is it possible to go level back in PHP namespace?

Tags: php, laravel

I have class in namespace:

```
App\Model\Product
```

Is it possible to use this class with level back, something like this:

```
App\Jobs..\Model\Product
```

?

Comment: after the namespace simply write `use App\Model\Product`

Comment: I know that this work, my question is if something like example above is possible...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Relative namespaces are not supported. Not sure why you would ever want to do that anyway.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? Can probably help you understand that better, because what you are asking should never be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

No, is is not possible.

Use the fully qualified name of the class:

```
use App\Model\Product;
$instance = new Product();
```

or just instantiate by the fully qualified name:

```
 $instance = new \App\Model\Product();
```

Answer (score 0):

Import the `Product` class with the `use` statement.

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs\Example;

use App\Model\Product;

$product = new Product;
```

Answer (score 0):

No. When talking about relative namespaces, PHP does not mention directory style name spacing — even though it uses file systems as an analogy.

I can't think of a reason to ever need to do what you are asking.

Read more at http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php